# WP_Query from searching post except and not page title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type named 'Company' and a basic search on the top right of the screen. Unfortunately, when submitting a basic search the search results populate companies instead of actual pages such as Resources or Tech Advisory Group. http://labbureau.wpengine.com/

I have modified my custom query to search only for pages and ignore all company posts however, the basic search is still displaying companies instead of the actual TITLES of the pages. What can be done of this?

Below is my custom query:

```
$keyword = $_GET['s'];
             $wp_query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    's' => $keyword,
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'company',
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                            ),
                    'orderby' => 'title'
                    )
                );
```

Start of loop:

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: where exactly is the problem - the query returning unexpected results OR the query is returning the right results but isn't displaying the page's title?

Comment: Page titles are displaying along with excerpt content. Interestingly if I did a search for "Information" the search archive might display 3 posts or pages with the word "Information" in the snippet however the last couple of pages/posts may not visually show the search word. Yes the query is returning unexpected results...

Answer (score 0):

Try add hidden input in the search form with the post type you want to make the search on:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post_type_name" />
```

Comment: Why would this matter? Even if you grabbed the value through the URL you would still be adding 'page' as a string in the query.

Answer (score 0):

On your theme functions.php use this code

```
function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('page'));
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Comment: What I have forgotten to mention is that I have two different forms on  this site, one for custom post types and another just for a simple search. Is there a way to use this function with just the basic search and not for a custom post type search?

Comment: For custom post type search you can create a custom template and form.get the value of that form and use wp_query()

Comment: ...not for a custom post type search

Comment: searchfilter() function will work for basic search.So when you do a search it will just ignore all types of page and show result from others

Comment: So what would that look like to write this function for just one search form?

Comment: On my solution use searchfilter() function just for default wordpress search functionality and for custom field search only create a page template and make a custom form there.This [link](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/template/create-multiple-search-templates-for-custom-post-types/) may guide you

Comment: The search fields already have two different search results templates which are being called from a conditional statement based on a hidden field and not a custom post type. It is not a good practice to use conditional post types with conditional logic because if the scope changes you have to change the type in two places. In addition, the searchfilter() you previously provided overwrites the conditional logic and is more of a master rewrite for all queries on my website. Still broken...

Comment: If there is a brilliant way to utilize searchfilter() outside of the functions.php file but scoped just for one search results page that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. Go to your Media Gallery and do a search for  a file. If the search title is the same as the image title and no results display you have a conflicting query that is running rampant. More than likely this can be found in the functions.php file and is represented as a filter that looks like the following:

```
function search_filter( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('company') );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

The function.php file is the king of the hill and will take over all other custom post types you have on your website. If you have multiple searches they will both search for the company post type regardless of whether or not you create a new WordPress query in a template. You need to comment out add_filter. In this example, you need to create a conditional statement for two different search loops. One of your search templates (HTML) needs to have a hidden input that can be retrieved by one of your conditional points to reference a new template with a new query. Do not try the conditional statement with custom post types because you will have to change this in more than one place if it needs to be changed. Here is an example of what this conditional would look like:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_simple']) && $_GET['search_simple'] = 'search' && !isset($_GET['hdr-search']))
    {
        get_template_part('loop-search');
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['search_simple']) && $_GET['search_simple'] = 'search' && isset($_GET['hdr-search']))
    {
        get_template_part('loop-search2');
    }
    else
    {
        get_template_part('loop-search-blog');
    }
```